# Decode html script with java

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, struts2

I am trying to decode html script with java. The encoded html script is getting from the database. This is what I am trying in my action class.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    String afterDecoding = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(rs.getString("design"));
    System.out.println("afterDecoding-"+afterDecoding);
    design = afterDecoding;
}
```

My jsp (createreport.jsp) file.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="design">
    <s:property value="%{design}" />

</div>
```

This is how I am calling the action.

```
function createReport() {
    var reportID = $('#a1').text();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("GET", "createreport.action?reportID=" + reportID, true);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);

            document.getElementById("report_container").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

The thing I want to do is,

1. Get the encoded html script from the database-this is ok
2. I want to set this script as the content of a div. For this I tried following as above.

   **document.getElementById("report_container").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;**
   But that script is printing on my web page as a text, not as a html script.

Line **console.log(xhttp.responseText);** prints following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="design">
    &lt;fieldset&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;component&quot; data-content=&quot;&lt;form class='form'&gt;
 &lt;div class='controls'&gt;

 &lt;label class='control-label'&gt; Report Title &lt;/label&gt;
 &lt;input class='input-large field' data-type=&quot;input&quot;                    type='text' name='name' id='name' value ='Employee Details' /&gt;

 &lt;label class='control-label'&gt; Text Align &lt;/label&gt;
 &lt;select class=&quot;field&quot; data-type=&quot;select&quot; id='textalign'&gt;

 &lt;option value=&quot;text-left&quot;  &gt;Left&lt;/option&gt;

 &lt;option value=&quot;text-right&quot;  &gt;Right&lt;/option&gt;

 &lt;option value=&quot;text-center&quot;  selected         &gt;Centre&lt;/option&gt;

&lt;/select&gt;

&lt;hr/&gt;
&lt;button id=&quot;save&quot; class='btn btn-  info'&gt;Save&lt;/button&gt;&lt;button id=&quot;cancel&quot; class='btn btn-     danger'&gt;Cancel&lt;/button&gt;

 &lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;/form&gt;

 &quot; data-title=&quot;Form Name&quot; data-trigger=&quot;manual&quot;   data-html=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;!-- Title --&gt;
 &lt;h3 id=&quot;title-0&quot; class=&quot;text-center&quot;&gt;Employee Details&lt;/h3&gt;
 &lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;component&quot; data-content=&quot;&lt;form class='form'&gt;
 &lt;div class='controls'&gt;

 &lt;label class='control-label'&gt; Sub Title &lt;/label&gt;
 &lt;input class='input-large field' data-type=&quot;input&quot; type='text' name='subtitle' id='subtitle' value ='Summary Report' /&gt;

 &lt;label class='control-label'&gt; Text Align &lt;/label&gt;
&lt;select class=&quot;field&quot; data-type=&quot;select&quot;    id='textalign'&gt;

 &lt;option value=&quot;text-left&quot;  &gt;Left&lt;/option&gt;

 &lt;option value=&quot;text-right&quot;  &gt;Right&lt;/option&gt;

 &lt;option value=&quot;text-center&quot;  selected        &gt;Center&lt;/option&gt;

 &lt;/select&gt;

 &lt;hr/&gt;
 &lt;button id=&quot;save&quot; class='btn btn-    info'&gt;Save&lt;/button&gt;&lt;button id=&quot;cancel&quot; class='btn btn-    danger'&gt;Cancel&lt;/button&gt;

 &lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;/form&gt;

 &quot; data-title=&quot;Sub Title&quot; data-trigger=&quot;manual&quot;   data-html=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;!-- Sub Title--&gt;

 &lt;h5 id=&quot;subtitle-0&quot; class=&quot;text-center&quot;&gt;Summary Report&lt;/h5&gt;


 &lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;component&quot; data-content=&quot;&lt;form class='form'&gt;
&lt;div class='controls'&gt;


&lt;hr/&gt;
&lt;button id=&quot;save&quot; class='btn btn- info'&gt;Save&lt;/button&gt;&lt;button id=&quot;cancel&quot; class='btn btn- danger'&gt;Cancel&lt;/button&gt;

&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/form&gt;

&quot; data-title=&quot;Hr&quot; data-trigger=&quot;manual&quot; data- html=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;!-- hr --&gt;
&lt;hr&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;component&quot; data-content=&quot;&lt;form class='form'&gt;
 &lt;div class='controls'&gt; 

 &lt;label class='control-label'&gt; Border &lt;/label&gt;
 &lt;input class='input-large field' data-type=&quot;input&quot; type='text' name='border' id='border' value ='1' /&gt;

 &lt;label class='control-label'&gt; Columns &lt;/label&gt;
 &lt;textarea class=&quot;field&quot; data-type=&quot;textarea- split&quot;   style='min-height: 200px' id='columns'&gt;Column1
 Column2&lt;/textarea&gt;

 &lt;hr/&gt;
 &lt;button id=&quot;save&quot; class='btn btn-info'&gt;Save&lt;/button&gt;&lt;button id=&quot;cancel&quot; class='btn btn-danger'&gt;Cancel&lt;/button&gt;

 &lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;/form&gt;

 &quot; data-title=&quot;Table&quot; data-trigger=&quot;manual&quot; data-html=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;!-- Table--&gt;
 &lt;div class=&quot;control-group&quot; id=&quot;tablediv&quot;&gt;

 &lt;table id=&quot;table-0&quot; class=&quot;draggable&quot;     name=&quot;table-0&quot; border=&quot;1&quot;    style=&quot;width:100%&quot;&gt;
 &lt;tbody&gt;&lt;tr&gt;
 &lt;th&gt;Column1&lt;/th&gt;
 &lt;th&gt;Column2&lt;/th&gt;
 &lt;/tr&gt;
 &lt;/tbody&gt;&lt;/table&gt;

 &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/fieldset&gt;

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my struts.xml

```
<action name="createreport" class="net.java.com.reports.CreateReport"
        method="execute">
    <result name="success">/createreport.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This is how i am encoded the html script.

```
encodeURIComponent($('#target').html());
```

What an I missing with my codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to change:

```
<s:property value="%{design}" />
```

to

```
<s:property value="%{design}" escapeHtml="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need manipulating HTML I recommmed using jsoup for.

But for your stated purpose I think [unbescape](http://www.unbescape.org/). should be enough. It does HTML escaping for us.

HTML can be unescaped this way:

```
final String unescapedText = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(escapedText);
```

And you pass unescapedText text as requiered further to response.

> Escape operations are also extremely powerful, allowing you to
>   (optionally) determine the type and level of escape you want. For
>   example, this:

```
final String escapedText =
        HtmlEscape.escapeHtml(
                unescapedText,
                HtmlEscapeType.HTML4_NAMED_REFERENCES_DEFAULT_TO_DECIMAL,
                HtmlEscapeLevel.LEVEL_1_ONLY_MARKUP_SIGNIFICANT);
```

or

```
final String escapedText = HtmlEscape.escapeHtml4Xml(unescapedText);
```

Comment: How can I get the escapedText ?

Comment: encoded html is getting from the database as String type

Comment: @Ann18 RIght so just fetch that HTML from DB in a string named stringfetechedHTMLFromDB and do final String unescapedText = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(stringfetechedHTMLFromDB);

Comment: I tried final String unescapedText = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(rs.getString("design")); But I am getting an error as **The method unescapeHtml(String) is undefined for the type HtmlEscape**